# Bash: Multiple for loops in Background

Tags: bash, background-process, for, parallelism

Is this the correct way to start multiple sequential processings in the background?

```
for i in {1..10}; do
    for j in {1..10}; do
        run_command $i $j;
    done &
done;
```

All `j` should be processed after each other for a given `i`, but all `i` should be processed simultaneously.

Comment: What do you mean by "correct way"?

Comment: Mainly that it works. I was missing this on stackoverflow.

Comment: :-) I'm asking because your code works fine for me. If by "correct way" you mean best practice, then I would put inner loop in a function or even different file so its more clear

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The outer loop that you have is basically

```bash
for i in {1..10}; do
    some_compound_command &
done
```

This would start ten concurrent instances of `some_compound_command` in the background.  They will be started as fast as possible, but not quite "all at the same time" (i.e. if `some_compound_command` takes *very* little time, then the first may well finish before the last one starts).

The fact that `some_compound_command` happens to be a loop is not important.  This means that the code that you show is *correct* in that iterations of the inner `j`-loop will be running sequentially, but all instances of the inner loop (one per iteration of the outer `i`-loop) would be started concurrently.

The only thing to keep in mind is that each background job will be running in a subshell. This means that changes made to the environment (e.g. modifications to values of shell variables, changes of current working directory with `cd`, etc.) in one instance of the inner loop will not be visible outside of that particular background job.

What you may want to add is a `wait` statement after your loop, just to wait for all background jobs to actually finish, at least before the script terminates:

```bash
for i in {1..10}; do
    for j in {1..10}; do
        run_command "$i" "$j"
    done &
done

wait
```

Answer (score 4):

If you have GNU Parallel you would do:

```
parallel -j0 'for j in {1..10}; do run_command {} $j; done' ::: {1..10}
```

One of the benefits is that output from parallel running `run_commands` will not mix.